# Jnlp file is not downloading in internet explorer browser

Tags: java, jsp, applet, digital-signature, jnlp

I am having jsp file which will contain jnlp file content with dynamic parameters as given below,

```xml
<% response.setContentType("application/x-java-jnlp-file"); %>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/testJnlp/" href="verifyDSC.jsp?param=<%=request.getParameter("param")%>">
    <information>
        <title>Jnlp Signing</title>
        <vendor>test</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/testJnlp" />
        <description>Signing</description>
    </information>

    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>

    <resources> 
        <j2se version="1.6+"/>
        <jar href="JnlpVerifyDSC.jar" main="true"/>
    </resources>

    <application-desc main-class="package.VerifyDSC">
        <argument><%=request.getParameter("param")%></argument>
    </application-desc>
    <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

If i execute the above file in forefox&chrome the jnlp file is getting downloaded and working fine, but in IE it is throwing "page can’t be displayed" error.

Can you please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: I note the JNLP `application-desc` is for an application (e.g. `JFrame`) but the question has the [tag:applet] tag added (e.g. `Applet` / `JApplet`). Which is it? Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: Yes , actually this is replacement of an applet. i am invoking simple java class only. i have downloaded JaNeLA and analysed the above file but it is showing "Contenttype is not equal to expected type application/x-java-jnlp-file". the same content type only i gave. not sure where the mistake is.

Comment: Are you analysing the JNLP is provided by the sever (from an URL) or the raw JSP? *"actually this is replacement of an applet."* I'm still not clear. JNLP can launch applets, what does this class extend or otherwise use as the top level container?

Comment: "I'm still not clear. JNLP can launch applets"- Yes but we have replaced the applet with simple java class because as per the requirements we no need to use applet.this extends JFrame. i have verified jsp file only.

Comment: Just now i checked jnlp from URL, the content type of this file is getting added with char-set like--application/x-java-jnlp-file;charset=ISO-8859-1. so again the type mismatch error and another error called the "proccssing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed" is coming.

Comment: *"the content type of this file is getting added with char-set like--application/x-java-jnlp-file;charset=ISO-8859-1"* Well it's declared, and should be, UTF-8. You obviously need to tweak the JNLP to produce UTF-8 charset. *"and another error"* It's hard to know what causes that unless you publish a JNLP **after** the JNLP has filled in the values! Don't assume your audience are mind readers. BTW - I doubt fixing the problems will fix the problem with IE, but fix them anyway, just to turle it out.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue by adding below line to the jnlp file,

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=verifyDSC.jnlp");
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. :) (No, I won't continue the discussion in chat.)